# Why JSArray parsing behaves differently, depending on the code structure, while logic remained?

Tags: json, scala, parsing, playframework

I'm doing small refactoring, trying to keep logical outcomes intact:

After refactoring:

```
        val mapped:Seq[Option[String]] = (mr.getNormalizedValue(1) \ "getapworkflowinfo1" ).as[JsArray].value.map(v => {
            (v \ "Description").as[String] match {
                case value if List("referral to electrophysiology").exists(value.toLowerCase.equals) =>
                    Some("true")
                case _ =>
                    None
            }}
        )
        mapped.flatten.lastOption
```

To:

```
        val referralIndicators: Seq[Boolean] =
            (mr.getNormalizedValue(1) \ "getapworkflowinfo1").as[JsArray].value
            // Step 1.1 Extracting and checking description
            .map(d => (d \ "Description").as[String].toLowerCase().equals("referral to electrophysiology"))
        // Step 2. Returning if at least once there was referral to electrophysiology
        Some(referralIndicators.exists(v => v)).map(v => v.toString)
```

Which should be logically equal (and there for should generate the same outputs on the same inputs).

***Effectively improves parsing, and results returned in refactored code are better, then before.***

Can someone explain, what is the different between those two?

Comment: The logic definitely is not the same. At a glance, the latter can return `Some("false")` (I think), while the former never will.